# When i want to save multiple image to database it's only save the last on telegram

Tags: javascript, telegram, telegraf.js

```js
if (req[0].site == '1') {
    link = await bot.telegram.getFileLink(ctx.message.photo[ctx.message.photo.length - 1].file_id) // Save the last image
    await console.log(link.href) // Print the last image url to know it's the good
    await db.query(`UPDATE base SET photo = '${link.href} \n ${req[0].photo} ' where user = '${ctx.chat.id}'`) // To add to the database, but it's only save the last sended picture
    return;
}
```

I try to know where was the problem, change my db query but it's not that, check if all of my code is in await and it's good

Comment: How do you want to save multiple photos in the db? Currently it overwrites the previous value with `${link.href} \n ${req[0].photo}`, so the previous value is lost. Do you want to insert new rows instead (ie an INSERT statement)?

Comment: req[0].photo is my actual value in the database no ? so it will just add the new link before the last ? like "new link \n last link"

Comment: Then try logging `${link.href} \n ${req[0].photo}` to see if it is what you expected. It could be a race condition, wrong order, invalid data, etc

Comment: On a side note, if the picture is user controlled this would be vulnerable to SQL injection exploits

Comment: When i do `console.log(req[0].photo)` after the db query lines it's just output nothing, the value is only added for the last picture, like if i send 3 picture for 3 picture it will print nothing, but when i go to my db to check the url of the last picture is here, is just like the db.query is working only at the last loop

Comment: Do you try to insert the photos at the same time, or do you ensure it runs sequential? If you don't know you can check by logging at the start and end of each function and see if they overlap (e.g. `start-1`, `start-2`, `end-1`, `end-2`) or they are sequential (`start-1`, `end-1`, `start-2`, etc)

Comment: idk if it's the true response but i try to add some console.log between every link printed and this is the loop : 
print the link of picture 1
print i to separate
print the link of picture 2
print i to separate
print the link of picture 3